Is an algebraic complement of the space of eventually zero sequences in $\ell_2$ dense?
Let $U$ be the set of $(x_n)_n$ in $\ell_2$ such that there existe an $N$ such that $x_n=0$ for all $n>N$. Let $V$ be an algebraic complement of $U$ (ie, a subspace of $\ell_2$ such that $U+V=\ell_2$ and $U\cap V=\{0\}$).
Is is true that $V$ must be dense in $\ell_2$?
I have an intuition that it must be, since we are only removing algebraically $U$, which is a small subspace (in the sense of Baire, for example, or in the sense that it has a countable algebraic basis).
Is this common knowledge? How would you prove this?

No, this is not true. Let $W$ be the one-dimensional subspace spanned by $e_1$. Then $U = W \oplus (W^\perp \cap U)$. Let $V$ be an algebraic complement of $W^\perp \cap U$ in $W^\perp$. Then $V$ is an algebraic complement of $U$. But $V$ is contained in the closed proper subspace $W^\perp$, so $V$ is not dense in $\ell^2$.

Oh, thanks. I just spent a long time trying to prove it and wondering why i wasn't managing... turns out it was just false.

@SusanaSantoyo Since you seem to have never accepted any answer to your questions: If you find an answer satisfactory, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark to the left.
